# Firebase Functions cors

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase Functions and everything worked as intended when using the Ionic Native HTTP plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/).
Today, I decided to move towards the Angular-Http implementation, since I can test my code in the browser then too.

The issue I am facing is, since I moved away from the native approach and am using the Angular way to deal with Http, I get an error related to CORS:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

On the serverside I followed https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint and this worked fine, until I was using Angular for HTTP.

My code on the server looks as follows:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const router = new express.Router();
router.use(cors);
router.use(validateFirebaseIdToken);
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Proccess myFunction");
  ...
}
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onRequest(router);
```

Inside the firebase console, I get following log:

> 3:41:28.429 nachm. warning myFunction TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined at Immediate. (/user_code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:14) at runCallback (timers.js:639:20) at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:610:5) at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:582:5)
>
> 3:41:28.428 nachm. warning myFunction Uncaught exception
>
> 3:41:28.424 nachm. info   myFunction Proccess myFunction

So it looks like,my Function is being called and the log appears, but the connection gets lost somewhere between. As mentioned, it worked all fine before I used Angular Http. According to my additional log entries, the crash happens somewhere at that moment, when I try to access the Firebase storage (But since it worked before, I am pretty sure, that the access to the storage is fine).

Edit:
The values in the body seem to be undefined too.

```
console.log("ID "+req.body.userID);
```

prints:

> "ID undefined"

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found the issue.
On the requesting side, I had to use 'application/json' as Content-Type. Not sure why this raised a cors error, and why it worked that way before.

Comment: How exactly did you do that? Did you use `httpsCallable` from `AngularFireFunctions`? Could you provide an example?